# Check if the image exists to .setImage In Embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a "tweet" system. I check if the link is true and has an image but if you put something like `https://askhdkjahs.png` the program thinks is an image and put in the embed giving an error.

I need handle the error and put a default image or reply saying 'the image give a error'.

That's my code:

```js
if (comando === `${prefix}atwt`) {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 100 });
    if (!argumento[0]) {
        msg.reply('pon algo').then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
        }).catch(console.error);
    }
    else if(argumento !== null && argumento !== '') {
        const TweetAnon = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor('Anonimo!', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
            .setColor('BLUE')
            .setTimestamp();
        const url = argumento[0].toString();
        if (url.match(/^https.*\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i)) {
            TweetAnon.setImage(argumento[0]);
            TweetAnon.setDescription(`**${argumento.slice(1).join(' ')}**`);
        }
        else{
            TweetAnon.setDescription(`**${argumento.join(' ')}**`);
        }
        const msgEmbed = await msg.channel.send(TweetAnon).catch(TweetAnon.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png'));
        await msgEmbed.react('');
        await msgEmbed.react('');
        await msgEmbed.react('');
    }
}
```

I see something like that and I tried but doesn't work

```js
if (comando === `${prefix}atwt`) {
    const url = argumento[0].toString();
    const TweetAnon = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Anonimo!', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/769965806850670634/854834517709422602/anon.png')
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTimestamp();
    msg.delete({ timeout: 100 });
    try {
        if (!url.match(/^https.*\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid URL');
        }
        TweetAnon.setImage(argumento[0]);
        TweetAnon.setDescription(`**${argumento.slice(1).join(' ')}**`);
    }
    catch (error) {
        TweetAnon.setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
    }
    // else
    //     TweetAnon.setDescription(`**${argumento.join(' ')}**`);
    // }
    const msgEmbed = await msg.channel.send(TweetAnon).catch(err => console.log(err));
    await msgEmbed.react('');
    await msgEmbed.react('');
    await msgEmbed.react('');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the image exists like this:

```js
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

Usage:

```js
if(imageExists(argumento[0])){
    TweetAnon.setImage(argumento[0]);
}
```